# How would you write a program to reduce an equation?

Tags: c++, theory

I may be misinterpreting the exact phrasing on [the question about which I've been thinking](http://www.justin.tv/problems/prefixer), but I'm curious as to how one would reduce an equation of multiple variables.

I'm assuming factoring plays a major role, however the only way I can think of doing it is to break the equation into a tree of operations and search the entire tree for duplicate nodes. I'm assuming that there's a better way, since many web applications do this quite quickly.

Any better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume that the kind of reductions that they are looking for is that something like `(2 + 3) * x` should become `(* 5 x)` rather than `(* (+ 2 3) x)`.  In which case you can just recognize that subtrees are constant, and calculate them.

You can also use the associative and commutative laws to try to move things around first to assist in the process.  So that `2 + x + 3` would become `(+ 5 x)` rather than `(+ (+ 2 x) 3)`.

Take this idea as far as you want.  It has been deliberately given in an open-ended fashion.  I'm sure that they would be happy to see you automatically recognize that `x * x + 2 * x + 1` is `(* (+ 1 x) (+ 1 x))` instead of `(+ (+ (* x x) (* 2 x)) 1)` but you can do a lot of good reductions without going there.

Comment: I suppose I'm more interested in how one would go about this, than the actual answer to the problem. I got to the point of grouping like terms pretty quickly, but I'm stuck beyond that, whereas Wolfram and any number of math products treat factoring as if it's nothing.

Comment: Ah.  There are a lot of methods, and I don't know what they all are.  One possibility is to use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem to list all possible linear factors.  You can then try each one and see if it is a factor.  There are also explicit formulas using radicals for polynomials of degree 1, 2, 3, and 4.  Those can be simplified algebraically.  For 5th degree polynomials we have a test that finds all irreducible ones, and formulas for all remaining ones.  I'm not sure about higher degrees, but I'm sure the smart people at Wolfram know about it.

Answer (score 1):

The general solution is to write flex\bison translator and to reduce parsed expressions. When you have created a translation flow you can add rules like expr*expr + 2*expr + 1 -> (*expr expr) as simple as I write it here.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a stack. It is much simpler that way. A solution is posted here

> http://bluefintuna.wordpress.com/2008/07/15/infix-prefix/

Comment: That solution doesn't handle the reduction part of the problem.  Which is what is being asked about.

Answer (score 0):

One Problem is here what one considers as reduced: E.g. (I write it for better readeability in infix - but prefix it is similar) x * x + x + 2 + 2 * x, one obvious reduction would be x * x + 3 * x + 2, another one would be (x + 1) * (x + 2). As this are quite untrivial problems and from the wording of the assignment, I would assume you bring your equation in some canonical form (e.g polynomial, sorted with highest power to lowest (when you have more than one variable take to the sum of the powers) and reduce there the coefficients (calculate them when constant)).

Be careful that some optimizations may seem valid, but are not in general. E.g. dont reduce (/ (* x x) x) to x, as there the solution 0 is suddenly valid, which it was not before.